# Grafana select max from multiple fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

For context, my data in Elasticsearch looks like the following:

```
"data": {
            "errors": {
              "file/name/somewhere.kt": 7,
              "file/name/somewhereElse.kt": 1,
              "file/name/some.kt": 2,
              "file/name/where.kt": 4 
}
```

Now as far as I can see, in Grafana I can only filter on the exact name of the field (data.errors.file/name/somewhere.kt).

What I would like to do is a wildcard search that returns the name and number of the highest number. Something like:

```
data.errors.*
```

Which would then return:

```
"file/name/somewhere.kt": 7
```

As that's the one with the highest number of errors.
Unfortunately such a wildcard does not seem to work: it returns 0 results.
Is this possible, and if so, how? Possibly with a Lucene query?

Comment: The document as you posted it cannot be searched that way, because it is not a valid json: the keys repeat. If ES does index this document, it will store only one of those keys, and the value will be randomly chosen. Please specify  a valid JSON document.

Comment: Apologies @NikolayVasiliev I hadn't thought of that; I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you, makes more sense now. May you please tell how does the data end up in Grafana?

Comment: What do you mean? Grafana pulls its data directly from my Elasticsearch instance. When using the query builder in Grafana, I can only select "data.errors.file/name/somewhere.kt", or any of the others. What I would like to do is query for the data.errors.* file with the highest number of errors.

Comment: I mean Grafana is not part of Elasticsearch, so it does some query to retrieve data. How do you specify the query? Is it possible to edit the query? If it is not, the only thing you can do is change how the data is stored in the Elasticsearch to smth like this: `[{"filename": "file/name/f1", "errorCount":7},{"filename": "file/name/f2", "errorCount":4}]`.